# Actualizar varias tablas al mismo tiempo Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Intento actualizar tres tablas en Oracle, que son totalmente distintas, pero que en todas existe un campo exactamente igual "STATUS".

El tema es que necesito que estos campos necesito que se actualicen a "NEW".

Es por esto que me he preguntado si es posible hacer actualización de multiples tablas a la vez.

Pensé en algo como esto, sin embargo me arroja error:

```
UPDATE SS_WERUECK, SS_BESTELLUNGR, SS_KOMMBESTR
SET STATUS = 'NEW';
```

Quedo atento de antemano lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a realizar un procedimiento:

```
Declare
  cursor t is select table_name from user_tables where table_name in ('tabla1','tabla2'...); -- Colocas tus tablas entre comillas simples ('') y lo aloja en un cursor
begin
  for t1 in t loop -- Recorremos nuestro cursor
      execute immediate 'update '|| t1.table_name || ' set STATUS=''NEW'''|| '  where STATUS=''Status_a_cambiar'''; -- Ejecuta el update a nuestras tablas segun nuestro cursor
  end loop;
    commit;  -- Guarda los cambios si no se tuvo error de ninguna actualización   
exception when others then -- Captura si hay error
    rollback; -- Devuelve todos los cambios realizados a las tablas
end;
```

Esto también es aplicable en caso de querer eliminar datos en tablas. En caso de  que estas estén indexadas, habrá que eliminarlas en cascada considerando el orden de la primera tabla como el dato que primero se debe eliminar, hasta el 
último que se puede eliminar una vez que no existe lugar que indexe con aquella tabla. Para dicho caso recordar cambiar "update" por "delete".

Comment: Vi un par de peros en tu código, por lo cual haré modificación de él para futuros usuarios. Pero la idea esta buena y haciendo esos detalles funciona!!!!

Answer (score 1):

No existe una sentencia `UPDATE` que te permita hacerle un update a las 3 tablas de un solo. Pero en realidad, eso no debería importar.

Si lo que deseas es que todas los cambios se apliquen de forma atómica, es solo cuestión de que los cambios se hagan todos dentro de la misma transacción:

```
update SS_WERUECK set status = 'NEW';
update SS_BESTELLUNGR set status = 'NEW';
update SS_KOMMBESTR set status = 'NEW';
commit;
```

Y si realmente deseas que los 3 updates se hagan dentro de una misma sentencia por la razón que sea, siempre puedes hacerlo mediante un bloque PL/SQL anónimo:

```
begin
    update SS_WERUECK set status = 'NEW';
    update SS_BESTELLUNGR set status = 'NEW';
    update SS_KOMMBESTR set status = 'NEW';
end;
/
commit;
/
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido repetir constantemente la misma función para actualizar, por ello era mas sencillo ir uno por uno cambiando el nombre de la tabla simplemente. Y coloque solo tres tablas como ejemplo, por que son bastante mas en realidad. Agradezco de todas formas tu respuesta

Comment: Mas sencillo no es siempre mejor. Como solo habías mencionado que debías manejar 3 tablas, me pareció razonable repetir un poco. Aunque obviamente se puede usar SQL dinámico, como en la otra respuesta, toma en cuenta que su uso facilmente puede esconder errores sin que te des cuenta. Por ejemplo, si escribes mal una tabla en el `where table_name in (...)`, nunca te vas a enterar que no le hicistes un update a una de las tablas. En ese caso, sigo prefiriendo escribir las sentencias `UPDATE` explícitamente, para que el compilador Oracle valide las sentencias.

Comment: Por otro lado, si la lógica que necesitas es que quieres hacerle un update a todas las tablas que tienen un columna `STATUS`, allí es diferente, y me parece una buena idea hacerlo con SQL dinámico, y sin tener que ir listando los nombres de las tablas uno a uno en una claúsula `IN (...)`. Todo depende de lo que estás haciendo en realidad.